# Auth0 SPA + API. How do I get the email, phone, and other info on my API?

Tags: node.js, jwt, auth0

In my React app, I'm using Auth0 Provider like this:

```
<Auth0Provider
  domain="xxx.us.auth0.com"
  clientId="xxxxxx"
  authorizationParams={{
    redirect_uri: window.location.origin,
    audience: 'api.xxxx',
    scope: 'openid profile email',
  }}
>
  <App />
</Auth0Provider>
```

In my nodeJS backend, I've set up the verifyAuth middleware like this -

```
import { auth } from 'express-oauth2-jwt-bearer';

const verifyAuth = auth({
  audience: 'api.xxxx',
  issuerBaseURL: 'https://xxxx.us.auth0.com/',
  tokenSigningAlg: 'RS256',
});

export default verifyAuth;
```

How can I get the user's email and phone number in my nodeJS backend?

I want to set up a `findOrCreate` functionality, and when I inspect the `req.auth` after running through middleware, I see this:

```
{
  payload: {
    iss: 'https://xxxx.us.auth0.com/',
    sub: 'auth0|xxxxxx',
    aud: [ 'xxxx.xxxx', 'https://xxxx.us.auth0.com/userinfo' ],
    iat: 1695839707,
    exp: 1695926107,
    azp: 'xxxxxxxxx',
    scope: 'openid profile email'
  },
  header: { alg: 'RS256', typ: 'JWT', kid: 'xxxxxx' },
  token: 'eyJhbGciO..............xxxxx'
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default, your JWT from Auth0 will only contain the basic fields from the JWT spec. If you want more information, you can add this in an Auth0 action running at login.

Add an Action under `Actions -> Library` that extends your JWT.
Add the Action under `Actions -> Flows -> Login`.

The Action may look something like this:

```
exports.onExecutePostLogin = async (event, api) => {
    api.accessToken.setCustomClaim("email", event.user.email)
    api.accessToken.setCustomClaim("emailIsVerified", event.user.email_verified)
    console.log(`User ${event.user.user_id} extended jwt with ${event.user.email}`)
  };
```

Note that the console log is stored as a log entry, but I personally found it somewhat hard to find. You will find it under `Monitoring -> Logs -> "Success Login" -> Details -> Action Details`

Comment: Thanks! That worked! Just wondering, does auth0 do this for security reason or something? As in, they want us to use their /userinfo endpoint to grab this data instead of putting it into the token?

Comment: @lkp If it worked, you are welcome to upvote and mark as answer. :-) They do this because the JWT is basically sent in every request, so it's a lot of payload that may not be used that often and causes some traffic overhead. Personally I tend only include the `sub` (user id) and possibly some `scopes`. What is needed for my initial reverse-proxy/api-gateway to validate if the user has access to the requested resource or not. The different resources digs up the data they need from the `sub`, using a DB or Auth0. But if you use the email a lot (like in most requests), it's fine to include it.

Comment: Done. Thank you friend.